# how to make an extension that targets an enum in C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm trying to make an extension that targets enum types, but it seems it only works on the items in the enum, not the whole enum itself.

**Enum**:

```
public enum Demo
{
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo,
    ValueThree
}
```

**Extension**:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEnum> AsEnumerable<TEnum>(this TEnum source) where TEnum : Enum, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    foreach(TEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This works:

```
var demo = Demo.ValueOne.AsEnumerable();
```

but I'm looking for:

```
var demo = Demo.AsEnumerable();
```

I had to create a separate method for this resulting in a syntax like this:

```
var test = EnumExtensionHelper<BaseAttributes>.AsEnumerable();
```

but it would look and feel much better with an extension method directly on the object

Comment: You can't create type extension methods, i.e. adding methods to types the way you can add "instance" methods to extend instances. Extension methods require an instance.

Comment: @madreflection ok I see. so it can't be done. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to madreflection it's solved. the answer is

"You can't create type extension methods, i.e. adding methods to types the way you can add "instance" methods to extend instances. Extension methods require an instance." - madreflection